# Вводится координата (х и у) . Определить попадает ли эта координата в закрашенную область

Tags: php, javascript

Определить попадает ли точка в закрашенную область или нет. Нужна функция на PHP или JS или хотя бы формулу с объяснением. Заранее спасибо))
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не уверен что вы предоставили достаточно данных, чтобы вам кто-либо мог что-либо подсказать. Чем определена закрашенная область? Я так понимаю есть какие-то функции описывающие данные фигуры? Какие у них параметры и прочее.. И да, думаю это вопрос больше по математике чем по php или js

Comment: @Alex Nem, согласен данных маловато, но это всё что было в задании, и задание по теме JS и PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 <= R^2 

   function foo(int $x, int $y, float $radius_min = 1,float $radius_max = 2){
      $x0 = -2;
      $y0 = 0;


      if($x >= -1){
        return TRUE;
      }

      $radius = sqrt(pow($x - $x0, 2) + pow($y - $y0, 2));


      return  $radius_min <= $radius && $radius <= $radius_max;

    }
```